# jQuery/AJAX send autogenerated Email without form and stay on page

Tags: php, ajax, email, jquery

I know this is a widely covered subject, but I kept searching the Web and couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.

What I am trying to do with jQuery/AJAX (as mentioned in the title):

I DON'T want any sort of Form that the user can fill out.
I just want a button (some HTML-Element) that when clicked sends an automatically generated mail to a predefined addess.
Neither the content nor the subject or anything else needs to be "filled in" by the viewer/user.

There will only be one variable (a script will insert the right value) that should be put somewhere in the content of the Email.

On clicking the button, the mail should be sent, the button should be replaced by a "Thanks whatever..."-message and that's IT!
No redirecting to another page or whatnot.

What I found that might be useful so far:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "...",
       url: "...",
       cache: ...,
       contentType: "...",
       data: "{ 'body':'"  + myMsg + "'," +
                 "'to': '" + myAddr + "'," +
                 "'from': 'AUTOMAILER'," +
                 "'subject': " + mySubject + mySpecVar + "'" +
             "}",
       dataType: "...",
       complete: function (transport) {  if (transport.status == 200) $("#myButtonContainer").html("Success"); else alert("Please try again later"); }
   });
```

Let's say my HTML is:

```
<p id="notify">Notify!</p>
```

And my JS-part would start something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#notify").click(function(){

            // THE JQUERY/AJAX STUFF HERE?

        });
    });
</script>
```

I assume I need at least some sort of a .php-File as well? Apparently I still don't get it...

I still very much lack experience and would be very grateful for a solution, or even for a nudge in the right direction!

If this problem has already been solved for someone on this site, I apologize. I didn't find it.

**EDIT :** This should all happen on the client-side (as far as possible). Meaning that the Email content is ultimately generated on the client-side. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mention something important. That "script" that generates the email content is it client or server side?

All you need is the clickable element:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doStuff()">Send</button>
```

The ajax method:

```
<script>
function doStuff()
{
    //var data =... ANY DATA YOU MIGHT NEED
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "sample.php",
       data: data,
       dataType: "text"
    });
}
//ADD here some jquery to change the button text
</script>
```

And then you can easily find a php script to send email. You can hardcode the email address if it never changes

Comment: Why do I need a <button>? I can just use the $("#notify").click(function()... , can't I? And what do you mean "easily find a php script"?

Comment: Yes, you can use any html element, the button was just an example. By "easily find a php script" I man that if you google "php mail" or "php send email" you get thousand of results explaining how to send an email using PHP. If you know your destination address and you want to code the subject and body all you have to do is fill in those values on the results you find on google

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax approach is fine, but you need a server action (set in the "url") that will finally send the mail. The browser can't do it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Email sending is done server side ie php. post to an email.php file which then sends the email.   Make sure to use json functions in php too if you need to do a callback.